# stop refreshing when call jQuery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, reload

I wrote these simple code.my problem is that jquery works but after set scroll position my page is refreshing and settings refer it's default position.how can I stop refreshing?

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("div").scrollTop(30);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 150px; overflow: auto">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img width="80px" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" height="70px" alt="" class="img_gallery"
                src="Images_slider/1.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="80px" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" height="70px" alt="" class="img_gallery"
                src="Images_slider/2.jpg" />
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<br>
<button>
    Return the vertical position of the scrollbar</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Why you have a form there?

Comment: because I use asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return false` from the handler to prevent the default action of button click from taking place

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("div").scrollTop(30);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a new problem now.I'm trying to increase scroll top after each click and wrote this for it

    var x = $("div").scrollTop() + 30;
    $("div").scrollTop(x);
but in each call value of x is 30
how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Button will post the form.
When you will use button then you have to return false to stop the form to submit
Alternative you can use client html input button as i have provided below.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
 $(function () {
        $("#btncl").click(function (e) {
            $("div").scrollTop(30);      
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 150px; overflow: auto">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img width="80px" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" height="70px" alt="" class="img_gallery"
                src="Images_slider/1.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="80px" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" height="70px" alt="" class="img_gallery"
                src="Images_slider/2.jpg" />
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<br>
    <input type="button" value="Return the vertical position of the scrollbar" id="btncl">

</form>
```

Comment: I have a new problem now.I'm trying to increase scroll top after each click and wrote this for it

    var x = $("div").scrollTop() + 30;
    $("div").scrollTop(x);
but in each call value of x is 30
how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use either return false or a combination of e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation.

Return false from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation on the passed jQuery.Event object.

e.preventDefault() will prevent the default event from occuring, e.stopPropagation() will prevent the event from bubbling up and return false will do both. Note that this behaviour differs from normal (non-jQuery) event handlers, in which, notably, return false does not stop the event from bubbling up.